# Automatically resize document inside an html <object> element to fit within the dimensions of the object (perhaps with Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is it possible to automatically resize the document within an  element to fit within the dimensions of the object (perhaps with Javascript)?

I need to display previews of documents (such as PDFs, Word documents, etc) on a website.  The previews need to be live (of the actual document, not an image), and to be 240px-350px wide.

If I use the  element, the embedded document displays as per my requirements - i.e. showing the full width of the document in the available window set by the dimensions of the iframe.

However, if I use the  element, the embedded document is displayed by default at a much larger size, which means that only a portion of the document is visible in the object window - see screenshot.

Is there a way in which to force the document inside the  element to resize itself automatically to fit the dimensions set for the object element - i.e. to behave the same as the document inside the iframe?

I'm pretty sure that it can't be done by the properties on the  element.  However, I am wondering whether there is a Javacript workaround.  Note that on mouseover of the document a translucent toolbar pops up in Chrome and Safari (so long as the dimensions are at least 346 px wide), and that toolbar allows one to resize the document inside to fit it within the inframe window.  This hints that the document size can be changed (probably by Javascript).  My application needs to do this by default.

My code for both the iframe and the object versions is set out below.

```
<iframe src="sample01.pdf" height = "400" width ="350" >
</iframe>   

<object data="sample01.pdf" type="application/pdf" height="400" width="350">
    <embed src="sample01.pdf" type="application/pdf"/>
</object>
```

(I had also posted images of the two, but haven't yet earned enough reputation points to post images.)

Comment: That will largely depend on what plugin is used to display PDF/Word files within the browser (if any).

Comment: Is there any way to do this for the chrome PDF plugin specifically?